# How to solve for $3$ constants with $3$ equations

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I am working to solve a formula for population, where I have the following model:
$P(t)= M/(1+Ae^{-Mkt})$

I have the first data points for the model:
$(0,2700000), (1,3050000), (2,3450000)$

This gives me $3$ equations:

$2700000=M/(1+A),$

$3050000=M/(1+Ae^{-Mk})$

$3450000=M/(1+Ae^{-2Mk})$

However, I am not sure how to solve for each of the $3$ variables, $M, k$ and $A$?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve the problem. Here is another one : first let $e^{-Mk}=x$ and consider
$$2700000=\frac M{1+A} \tag 1$$
$$3050000=\frac M{1+A x} \tag 2$$
$$3450000=\frac M{1+A x^2} \tag 3$$
$$x=e^{-Mk}\tag 4$$
$$\frac{(1)}{(2)} \implies \frac{54}{61}=\frac{A x+1}{A+1}\implies A=\frac{7}{54-61 x} \tag 5$$
$$\frac{(1)}{(3)} \implies \frac{18}{23}=\frac{A x^2+1}{A+1}\implies x=\frac{144}{161}\implies A=-\frac{1127}{90}\tag 6$$ Now, from $(1)$ $M=-31110000$.

Now, using $(4)$
$$\frac{144}{161}=\exp({31110000 k})\implies k=-\frac{\log \left(\frac{161}{144}\right)}{31110000}$$

Answer (score 1):

Label your equations:  \begin{align*}
1:&  &  2\,700\,000 &= M/(1+A)  \text{,}  \\
2:&  &  3\,050\,000 &= M/(1+Ae^{-Mk})  \text{, and}  \\
3:&  &  3\,450\,000 &= M/(1+Ae^{-2Mk})  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Eliminate $k$ between 2 and 3, yielding
\begin{align*}
4:&  &  641\,872\,500\,000\,000 - 420\,900\,000 M + 69 M^2 \\
  &  &= A (-641\,872\,500\,000\,000 + 186\,050\,000 M)
\end{align*}

Eliminate $M$ between 1 and 4 to obtain
\begin{align*}
5:&  &  A &= -1127/90  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Substitute 5 into 1 to find \begin{align*}
6:&  &  M &= -31\,110\,000  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Then substitute 5 and 6 into 2 to find \begin{align*}
k &= \frac{\ln \left(\frac{161}{144} \right)}{-31\,110\,000}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hey Eric, How have you eliminated k between 2 and 3?

Comment: From 2: $k = \ln\left( \frac{\frac{M}{3\,050\,000}-1}{A} \right)/(-M)$ and from 3: $k = \ln\left( \frac{\frac{M}{3\,450\,000}-1}{A} \right)/(-2M)$.

Comment: When you set 2=3, what are the steps you follow to get 4?

Comment: @Adsp : Multiply both sides by $-2M$.  Recall that $2 \ln(x) = \ln(x^2)$ to move the $2$ into the logarithm.  Exponentiate both sides to remove the logs.  Now you have equality between two rational expressions in $A$, $A^2$, $M$, $M^2$ and constants.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=10^6.$ Using the first equation, one can solve for $A$ in terms of $M$ to get $A=\dfrac{M-2.7z}{2.7z}\;(1).$

Plugging this into the second equation gives $3.05z=\dfrac{M}{1+\frac{M-2.7z}{2.7z}e^{-Mk}}.$ Solving for $k$ in terms of $M$ yields $k=-\dfrac{1}{M}\ln\left(\dfrac{2.7z\cdot(M-3.05z)}{3.05z(M-2.7z)}\right)\; (2).$

Plug the values of $A$ and $k$ in terms of $M$ into the last equation and you will get the equation $0.0125z^2M^2+0.388875z^3M=0\Rightarrow M(0.0125z^2M+0.388875z^3)=0\Rightarrow M=-31.11z=\boxed{-31\space110\space 000}.$ Plugging this value into equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get that $k=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{31\space 110\space 000}\ln\left(\dfrac{144}{161}\right)}$ and $A=\boxed{-\dfrac{1127}{90}}.$